# Filler material effect on metal

Tags: homework

Okay, my teacher said that if a filler material is added to metal it is possible with increasing filler content to observer:

- Yield strength increase,
- Young modulus decrease,
- Resilience and elongation increase

But I thought that if young modulus decreases, wouldn’t  yield strength also decrease?

Comment: Your teacher could be correct, noting that "Resilience and elongation to increase", the stress-strain curve might have flattened towards the right, resulting in decreased E.

Comment: Hi, cheers guys. So how would it change from a molecular point of view too please for this to happen please? I thought that the filler would be preventing the atoms of the material to move?

Comment: About the only metal in the real world that comes close to the description are cast irons  . Graphite flakes or nodules are formed in the cast iron depending on chemistry and thermal processing. The modulus , strength and ductility are changed depending on graphite morphology and other factors.

Comment: And tungsten carbide type materials. The fracture resistance and cutting ability change according to the amount of cobalt or nickel binder. Because they are relatively brittle ,I do not remember properties like yield strength being reported.